# Import a shadowed module from a package

Tags: python, import, pytest, monkeypatching

This is my package structure:

```
.
├── src
│   ├── damastes
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── main.py
│   │   └── run.py
```

`__init__.py`:

```
from .run import *
```

`run.py`:

```
...
_ARGS
...
def _path_compare(path_x: Path, path_y: Path) -> Ord:
    return (
        ...
        if _ARGS.sort_lex
        else ...
    )
...
def run()
...
```

I can import whatever I wish *from* the `run` module, but not the module `run` itself. It did not inconvenience me until I had to provide the module for monkey patching:

`test.py`:

```
from src.damastes.run import _path_compare
...
def test_path_compare(monkeypatch):
    args = RestrictedDotDict(copy.deepcopy(CLEAN_CONTEXT_PARAMS))
    args.sort_lex = True
    monkeypatch.setattr(src.damastes.run, "_ARGS", args)
    assert _path_compare("alfa", "alfa") == 0
```

My trouble is that `monkeypatch.setattr()` requires *module* as a first parameter, but I can't supply it. `src.damastes.run` is actually a function. As it should be. The "short-circuit" is intentional.

The error:

```
AttributeError: <function run at 0x7f3392b9f790> has no attribute '_ARGS'
```

Experimentally, I supply `src.damastes`:

```
AttributeError: <module 'src.damastes' from '/src/damastes/__init__.py'> has no attribute '_ARGS'
```

Of course it has not. Is there a way to supply the `run` module to `monkeypatch.setattr()` without restructuring the existing package/import solution?

`from src.damastes.run import _path_compare` part somehow works, by the way.

Comment: Not sure if this is the root of your question, but `from .run import *` in `__init__.py` does not import names beginning with underscores, like `_ARGS`.

Comment: If you need for the `_ARGS` to be monkeypatched in order to test properly, then perhaps they should not be both hard-coded and "marked as private" (by using a leading underscore). Consider the principle of dependency inversion.

Comment: Indeed, it does not. I am not sure this is the root of my question too, for the time being

Comment: "`from src.damastes.run import _path_compare` part somehow works, by the way." Yes, because now that the `.run` is part of the "from" path, it can be resolved as referring to the module defined by `run.py`, rather than the `run` name defined in `src.damastes` (via the `__init__` auto-load).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Is there a way out, in my case?

Comment: Did you try just `import src.damastes.run` etc. in the test code?

Comment: That said, *normally* one doesn't unit-test things that aren't supposed to be part of the module interface. A test that ends with `assert _path_compare("alfa", "alfa") == 0` is missing the point; since `_path_compare` is an implementation detail, not functionality provided by the module, there isn't a reason to test what it does. The *entire point* of that conceptual separation is to make it so that, later on, the implementation of the important stuff *need not* depend on what `_path_compare` does, or indeed even on the fact of it existing.

Comment: Yes, there is `import src.damastes.run` in the test file. I would not argue that this particular test is really necessary. I suppose, however, that as an exercise it is good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `from src.damastes.run import _path_compare` works, it's clear that `src.damastes.run` is a valid module identifier.

But it looks like the `run` function is shadowing the `run` module. So consider using one of these tricks to access the module specifically:

```py
from src.damastes.run import _path_compare

# Consider using the sys.modules.
# This is a dictionary that maps module names to modules which have already been loaded.
# this should work because of the `from src.damastes.run import ...` statement above
import sys
run_module = sys.modules["src.damastes.run"]

# or you could use the `importlib` module:
import importlib
run_module = importlib.import_module("src.damastes.run")

# Once you have the module bound to a variable
# you can patch it:
monkeypatch.setattr(run_module, "_ARGS", "TESTING!")
assert run_module._ARGS == "TESTING!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to rename the module: `run.py` -> `shoot.py`:

`init.py`:

```
from .shoot import *
```

`test.py`:

```
import src.damastes.shoot as shoot
...
class TestNonPureHelpers:
    def new_args(self):
        return RestrictedDotDict(copy.deepcopy(CLEAN_CONTEXT_PARAMS))

    def test_path_compare(self, monkeypatch):
        args = self.new_args()
        monkeypatch.setattr(shoot, "_ARGS", args)
        args.sort_lex = True
        assert shoot._path_compare("10alfa", "2bravo") == -1
        args.sort_lex = False  # Sort naturally.
        assert shoot._path_compare("10alfa", "2bravo") == 1
```

The solution is kinda obvious, yet a bit uncomfortable. Not unthinkable for an *ad hoc* language like Python, but it is against the scope idea. Names inside the module should not conflict with the module name.

Is the renaming solution the only one possible?

Comment: I ran into this, so I ended up prefixing the module's name with an underscore. The only disadvantage now is that your user will be able to import this module and you could lose control of what you choose to export via __init__.py instead.